# unable to send mail from linux server using nodemailer

Tags: node.js, linux

i am trying to send mail after user gets registered.
I am using nodemailer for this.
my code for this look like this-

```
 var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service:"Mailjet", // sets automatically host, port and connection security settings
    auth: {
    user:'******',
    pass:'*******'
  }
});
var mailOptions = {
  to:mailTo,
  from:'******',
  subject:'user registered',
  text:'welcome user'
};
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, info) {
  if (err) {
    logger.debug('error in sending email ' + err);
  } else {
    logger.debug('Message sent: ' + info.response);
  };
```

Mail is going properly when i use this on my localhost on my window machine but when i use this on my remote server which is a linux server.
I get the following error :

> error--- { Error: Connection timeout
>       at SMTPConnection._formatError (/root/root/server/cq-code/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:557:19)
>       at SMTPConnection._onError (/root/root/server/cq-code/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:530:20)
>       at Timeout._connectionTimeout.setTimeout (/root/root/server/cq-code/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:248:18)
>       at ontimeout (timers.js:471:11)
>       at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:306:5)
>       at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:266:5) code: 'ETIMEDOUT', command: 'CONN' }  info----- undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code was working fine.The problem was on the server,actually the port used for SMTP was blocked by the digital ocean.So i raised a query with them and after unblocking of that port, thing worked as expected.